# Include count of subdocuments in schema

Tags: node.js, mongoose

In my NodeJS project, I'm creating Mongoose schemas as below:

```
//Likes Schema
var likesSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  postId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Post", required: 'Provide the news ID to which this comment belongs' },
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Likes', likesSchema);

//Post schema
var postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: 'Kindly enter the title' },
  description: { type: String, required: 'Kindly enter the description of the news' }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema);
```

Post is a schema that has a title and a description. Like is a schema that tracks number of likes for a particular post. So it has just postID.

Now I want to include "count" of likes as a variable in "Post" schema. I don't want to count the likes during query execution.
Is there any simple way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution after doing some trial and errors:

```
db.Post.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "Likes",
            localField:"_id",
            foreignField: "postId",
            as: "likes"
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            title: 1,
            description: 1,
            count: { $size: "$likes" }
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```